# Write in matrix form

Tags: matrices

$D_{βν} =∑^{n}_{µ=1}∑^{n}_{a=1}A_{µν}B_{αµ}C_{αβ}$

Since the first index of $B$ and $C$ is the same, I believe what we have here is:

$$\sum^{n}_{a=1}B_{αµ}C_{αβ} = B(C^{T})$$

So that the equation given means:

$D = ABC^{T}$

I am not sure if this is right, after the conclusion that $C$ is a transpose matrix, the index become confusing to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $D = ABC^T$ then:

$$D_{i,j} = (ABC^T)_{i,j} = \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n(AB)_{i,k} (C^T)_{k,j} =\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{\ell=1}^n A_{i,\ell}B_{\ell,k} C_{j,k} $$

So this is not right. The problem is that in fact:

$$ \sum_{\alpha=1}^nB_{\alpha\mu} C_{\alpha \beta} = \sum_{\alpha=1}^n(B^T)_{\mu \alpha} C_{\alpha \beta} = (B^TC)_{\mu \beta} $$